# Bash output restrictions

Tags: windows, bash, output, global, restriction

I need to determine if a user is in a certain group.

I am currently using this line in command prompt.

```
whoami /groups > Desktop\output.txt
```

Unfortunately it is giving a lot of information I do not want.

Is there a way to restrict the command to only output Group names where the Type = Group?

Thanks,

-Childish

Example of my output (Just a template)

```
Group Name                              Type             SID                                              Attributes                                                     
======================================= ================ ================================================ ===============================================================
Everyone                                Well-known group #1                                          Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group      
Pizza                                   Group            #2                                          Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
```

I gave 2 "examples" above.  In this situation, I would only want the Group name "pizza" out of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with bash on windows, although in most versions you could pipe your output to awk:

```
whoami /groups | awk '$1 == "Pizza"' > Desktop\output.txt
```

This should only output lines which contain `Pizza` in column one. Another example by "Type":

```
whoami /groups | awk '$2 == "Group"' > Desktop\output.txt
```

This should only output lines which contain `Group` in column two.

**Output:**

```
Pizza                                   Group            #2                                          Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
```

Comment: You're welcome! If this solved your issue be sure to mark it as "correct answer".

Comment: Oops,my apologies I forgot. Sorry about that!